# Who are the main exponents (and books) on Design Strategy?

Tags: website-design, business

At my web shop we have been studying [Content Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_strategy) to implement it and raise the business value of our web development service/product. Upon modelling our business process I stumbled upon what seems to be the parallel equivalent of CS: [Design Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_strategy).

Now, we've been able to understand CS thanks to [Colleen Jones' "Clout"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321733010) and [Christina Halvorson's "Content Strategy for The Web"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321620062), so I'm wondering if there are any prominent books/ultimate-references for Design Strategy.

Comment: Nothing on the Wikipedia page is real, not one source is valid. It sounds like venture capitalists in San Francisco made up these terminologies to create self-wealth and purpose for their jobs. Think Dilbert comic strips. Instead of being a Marketer they're calling themselves Design Strategists and Experiential Designers.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the examples on the Wikipedia pages, it appears that [Design Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_strategy) may well be just a new term for product/brand development, and [Content Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_strategy) a new term for the editorial process.

And in fact the Design Strategy page could do with some serious "content strategy" applied:

> .. interplay between design and
> business strategy, forming a systematic approach integrating
> holistic-thinking, research methods used to inform business strategy
> and strategic planning which provides a context for design...
>
> Translating insights into actionable solutions ...

Continuing on my "nothing new under the sun" theme, for initial inspiration I'd recommend looking up [Raymond Loewy](http://www.raymondloewy.com) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Loewy)), the prolific industrial designer who managed to both cover everything from graphics to locomotives *and* popularised the whiole idea of products being designed at all:

> Shell and former BP logos, the Greyhound bus,
> the Coca-Cola bottle, the Pennsylvania Railroad GG1 and S-1
> locomotives, the Lucky Strike package, Coldspot refrigerators, the
> Studebaker Avanti and Champion, and the Air Force One livery.